# how to load two view CodeIgniter ($data and compact ) in same time

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I am new in the CodeIgniter framework and tried to make this work at the same time but not working

else if I stop one of it this line

```
1- $this->load->view('account/build_profile', $data);

2 - $this->load->view('account/build_profile',compact('country','industry'));
```

of this code

```
 function build_profile(){
        if($this->session->has_userdata('cus_id')){
        $status=$this->my_function->complete_status($this->session->cus_id);
        if($status==0){
        $query=$this->query_model->select1("cn_id,cn_name","ambit_country");
        $country=$this->query_model->details($query);
        $query=$this->query_model->select1("ind_id,ind_name","industry",array("status"=>1));
        $industry=$this->query_model->details($query);

        $data['page'] = 'country-list';
        $data['title'] = 'country List | TechArise';
        $data['geCountries'] = $this->account->getAllCountries();   

        $this->load->view('account/build_profile', $data);
        $this->load->view('account/build_profile',compact('country','industry'));
  }
```

Comment: as from the documentation https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html
Your can pass as array 

    $data = array(
                     'title' => 'My Title',
                       'heading' => 'My Heading',
            'message' => 'My Message'
    );

    $this->load->view('blogview', $data);

Comment: Why are you loading same view twice?

Answer (score 2):

Try this hope it will help you

```
$data['country'] = $this->query_model->details($query);
$data['industry'] = $this->query_model->details($query);
$data['page'] = 'country-list';
$data['title'] = 'country List | TechArise';
$data['geCountries'] = $this->account->getAllCountries(); 

$this->load->view('account/build_profile', $data);
```

In the view get all the data like:

```
echo $page; //country-list
echo $title; //country List | TechArise
print_r($geCountries); //Countries list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array from controller to view

```
function build_profile(){
    if($this->session->has_userdata('cus_id')){
    $status=$this->my_function->complete_status($this->session->cus_id);
    if($status==0){
    $query=$this->query_model->select1("cn_id,cn_name","ambit_country");
    $country=$this->query_model->details($query);
    $query=$this->query_model->select1("ind_id,ind_name","industry",array("status"=>1));
    $industry=$this->query_model->details($query);


    $data['page'] = 'country-list';
    $data['title'] = 'country List | TechArise';
    $data['geCountries'] = $this->account->getAllCountries();   



     $this->load->view('account/build_profile', ['data' => $data, 'compact' => compact('country','industry')]);
```